# Describing an action of a fight

Tags: word-choice, word-request, image-identification

[image: man's hand with another man's collar in his fist]

How would you describe this action?

Is he holding or grasping or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he is holding or grasping the shirt.  These words are synonyms in this context.

Perhaps, given the active nature of a fight, you might say that he has grabbed the shirt, or grabbed the collar.